# MVC and Meta Tags for Search Engine Optimization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, seo

I am working on mvc2. I want used Meta tags. I am new on the meta tags and seo. How can used meta tags on my page? What is the best way to used meta tags on mvc?

Answer (score 3):

From a programmer/technology point of view: meta tags are just tags.

What the content of your meta tags should be, and how to generate them, is application specific.

- [Google's article on meta tags](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=79812)
- [W3schools has a nice simple article](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_meta.asp)

Answer (score 3):

Meta tags play an ever decreasing role in SEO these days.

However, in relation to MVC, you can set your masterpage up along the following lines:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
    </title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder  
        ID="MetaPlaceHolder" runat="server">
        <meta name="keywords" content="<%= ViewData["keywords"] %>" />
        <meta name="description" content="<%= ViewData["description"] %>" />
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    // lots os stuff missed out!!
</head>
<body>// more suff missed etc</body>
```

and then pass the ViewData from your individual **controller actions** to populate the 'keywords' and 'description' sections. There are other ways, but this one is fairly simple to get up and running without major disruption to your existing codebase.

usage - add the following to each required controller action

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // data would obviously come from some datastore but hardcoded for now below
    ViewData["keywords"] = "speed, camera, action";
    ViewData["description"] = "crime dun wrong";
    // other stuff happening too
}
```

That said, you should more importantly be looking at:

- keyword density
- outbound/inbound links
- img alt tags
- page titles
- H1/H2 contents
- long URL segmentation and applicability

as these play an ever increasing importance in SEO these days. all of the above should be easily searchable on google.

Comment: "pass the ViewData from your individual views", say what? Isn't it more likely that the action methods will be involved? :)

Comment: controller actions -yes, my 'bad' was typing too fast :) - changed above

Comment: This is an elegant solution.  Although, it would be nice to wrap the viewdata display in a conditional statement so that every page in the application does not have to send meta data.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jim is over-complicating it just a bit with the placeholder bit - it's not necessary. Just do this:

In _Layout head section:

```
<meta name="description" content=@ViewData["Description"]/>
```

In the controller:

```
ViewData["Description"] = "My site has all the goodies!!";
```

Also no need to wrap it in a conditional; it won't throw an error. If you don't set ViewData in the controller the tag will just be empty:

```
<meta name="description"/>
```